# Android - MediaRecorder output to stream for ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I'm trying to stream the content of my screen to an rtmp server, and I believe the easiest/best way to do that is using ffmpeg.

So, here's what I have so far:

```
try {
    Socket socket = new Socket(url, port);
    ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);

    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int orientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation + 90);
    mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
    mMediaRecorder.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In here, the important portion is

```
Socket socket = new Socket(url, port);
ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);

mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
```

So, when I place this inside an Asynctask I can make it attempt to send something, but I get a `UnknownHostException`

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "rtmps://rtmp-api....": No address associated with hostname
```

So, I've been told that I should use ffmpeg for this instead, but I don't know how to get the original stream from MediaRecorder to pass it to ffmpeg.

If I understand correctly, ffmpeg be used as:

```
-i original_stream rtmps://rtmp-api...
```

So, how can I get output content of MediaRecorder in a format that I could use in ffmpeg for streaming (not with a saved file).

Thanks!

Comment: I am facing same issue, were you able to resolve this one?

Answer (score 1):

Could not comment so i'll leave this as an answer even it is a bit too late, but this project should be what your looking for: https://github.com/danielkucera/ZidoStreamer

Comment: thanks. that shows some promise, although I'll have to use this code and see if it really does what I need.
I'll keep you updated.